# How can I delete spaces in words? (itextSharp, PdfReader, C#, ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

When I transfer pdf files to the textbox with itextsharp (PdfReader), my all pdf's text looks like this: w o r d    (long space)      w o r d        (long space)      w o r d

(I copied this code from one video to my own project. I don't know how it works. So, please suggest that I make changes considering that I don't know anything.)

```
string strText = string.Empty;
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path + dlg.FileName);
            for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy its = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
                String s = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page, its);

                s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Convert(System.Text.Encoding.Default, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s)));
                strText = strText + s;
                txtPdf.Text = strText;
            }
            reader.Close();
```

Comment: I saw your answers in similar questions but I did not understand. Where do I write the codes, methods in the answers? @mkl

Comment: Actually that appears to be an issue related to the pdf. Can you share it for analysis?

Comment: Sorry for answering late. You can download it from the link I added to my question

Comment: Can you let me know when you download because I'm not sure if it's legal :)

Comment: I just downloaded. But I won't have time to look into this today.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace spaces in a string using [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_).

Here is an example for your case:

```
...
s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Convert(System.Text.Encoding.Default, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s)));
strText = strText + s.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
...
```

Also check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/intro-to-csharp/hello-world) to get started.

Edit: You might be running into tabs ('long spaces') as well, which you could replace with spaces using the same pattern (where `\t` is used to represent a tab, see [String Escape Sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/#string-escape-sequences) for further information):

```
strText = strText + s.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace('\t', ' ');
```

Note: This only works for documents where words are separated using tabs, you might need to adapt your replacement logic depending on which document you process.

Comment: Did you have a look at `strText`? It should contain the text without spaces. Is there something else that you want to have improved?

Comment: Thank you very much for solving this gaps problem. So, in my last comment I mean, can we write a condition code for this code to work only on documents with spaces?

Comment: That sounds like a tricky and fragile approach. Nevertheless, you could experiment with wrapping the replacement in an if, checking for a pattern that only occurs in the type of documents where you want to remove whitespaces, e.g.  `s.Contains("\t ")`, which checks for a tab followed by a whitespace using [String.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains).